# how can i mute an iframe on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 pages, one is a video playing using html video tag
the other is an iframe of the first page.

I want to mute audio in iframe on keypress

The pages are not on the same domain.

this is the code I tried

```
 function cynMute(){
            const myElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
            if(myElement.muted === false) {
                myElement.muted = true          
            }
            else{
                myElement.muted = false          
            }
            
        }
        document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            cynMute()
        }
        });
```

which works on the first page but it doesn't work when I try to press enter on the second page. I tried putting the code with the respective ids on the second page but still nothing.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but you could replace your entire `if/else` with `myElement.muted = !myElement.muted;`

Comment: Have you tried `postMessage`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand, you are not able to select the video element inside your iframe. The same function will not work because this time `#myVideo` is not in the document.

You will have to get your iframe first and the query inside it using [contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow).

```
function cynMuteForIframe(){
let iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
if(iframe !=null){
const myElement = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myVideo");            
//Rest of your code
            if(myElement.muted === false) {
                myElement.muted = true          
            }
            else{
                myElement.muted = false          
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work but I suspect i'm implementing it wrong?
the video id is myVideo 
`function cynMuteForIframe(){
  let iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  if(iframe !=null){
  const myElement = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myVideo");            
   if(myElement.muted === false) {
    myElement.muted = true          
   }
   else{
    myElement.muted = false          
   }
   
  }
 }

 document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
 if (event.keyCode == 13) {
  cynMuteForIframe()
 }
 });`

Comment: Add some console.logs to check. It is very difficult to say anything without having the actual code. Is your id for iframe myFrame? What does console.log(myFrame) day